# can not display chinese traditional language in android app

Tags: android

I have array folder:

```
<string-array name="language">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>Chinese Simplified</item>
    <item>Chinese Traditional</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="language_values">
    <item>en</item>
    <item>zh</item>
    <item>zh-rTW</item>
</string-array>
```

I have put folder name "values-zh-rTW" in res folder and android studio only shows zh in translation editor

now as per my code, I can select English and Chinese simplified but when I select Chinese traditional from settings English is displayed do not why?

here is my code to get language and set language:

```
private String getLanguage(Context c, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
        return preferences.getString("language", defaultLanguage);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setLanguage(Context context, String languageCode) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
        }

        context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("language", languageCode);
        editor.apply();

    }
```

Comment: afaik, you need to restart the whole app to change the language. You can learn it from [Android-LocalizationActivity](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-LocalizationActivity)

Comment: i am already restating the app ,as i said already english and simplified chinese can be changed to appropriate after restarting but when i select traditional chinese on restart english is shown maybe language code is the problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

got it ,if you guys are using language which uses something like this zh-rTW or anylanguage-blabla

then you have to split the language code "-" and then pass second parameter in

```
Locale locale = new Locale("zh","TW");
```

done everything work as expected

Comment: Thanks it works, while Locale locale = new Locale("zh_TW"); doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

Loading Traditional Chinese string resources has changed slightly in Android 7+ (API 24). To support Traditional and Simplified Chinese at the same time in your app, you must now explicitly create a minimum of 2 language files:

- **`values-zh/strings.xml`** -- For Simplified Chinese `(zh, zh-CN, zh-SG)`
- **`values-zh-rTW/strings.xml`** -- For Traditional Chinese `(zh-TW, zh-HK)`

If you don't include the `values-zh-rTW/strings.xml`, then **Android 7 devices will fall back to English, not Simplified Chinese**. It's unusual and confusing. (Android 6 and below will fallback to values-zh - Simplified Chinese, and only requires one language file)

More info:

- https://gist.github.com/amake/0ac7724681ac1c178c6f95a5b09f03ce#new-locales-vs-old-locales-chinese
- https://fabiohub.wordpress.com/2016/12/31/chinese-locale-in-android/
- https://blog.egorand.me/a-curious-case-of-multiple-locales/

Comment: so I don't need values-zh-rHK/strings.xml for Hong Kong region right?

Comment: @RichardFu, That's correct, yes. To support 'Chinese, Hong Kong (Traditional)' language, Android 7 will use the file in values-zh-rTW/strings.xml (for Chinese-Taiwan), whereas Android 6 will use the file in values-zh/strings.xml (if you don't have a zh-rHK file). You can verify this with the 'MoreLocale 2' app, to change the system language more easily.

Comment: but that sounds bad, all Android pre-6 in HK will show Simplified Chinese... should it be better we use zh for Traditional and zh-rCN for Simplified Chinese?

Comment: @RichardFu, Yes you could change it around like that (having values-zh as Traditional Chinese and values-zh-rCN as Simplified Chinese), but it's problematic for 2 reasons: 1: It doesn't work on Android 7, because setting the language to 'Chinese, Hong Kong (Traditional)' or 'Chinese, Taiwan (Traditional)' will fallback to English. 2: On Android 6 it works ok, but the default Chinese would be Traditional Chinese, in a world where Simplified Chinese is becoming more popular now. So you would need to have a minimum of 3 language files for that to work.